# When do you go from morpheme to word to sentence in agglutinative languages?

Tags: words, meaning, agglutination, study-of-terms

I am [working on](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/vnzj18/how_to_structure_terms_in_crosslinguistic_database/) a cross-language dictionary for fun (i.e. every language), and have been refining this idea of "terms" (as described in that link) for a while. A term is basically anything which can have a definition. This includes morphemes (smallest units of meaning), and also lexemes, but also noun phrases ("ice cream"), but not phonemes or sentences, I don't think.

What I'm trying to consider, not having a deep level of knowledge/awareness of agglutinative languages like Turkish, Inuktitut, or some of the Native American languages, is how you distinguish "words" from "sentences", given that "words" can be complete sentences. The idea of a "[word](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/do-any-languages-not-have-the-concept-of-words)" I'm going with is "things which have spaces around them", because that's really what it is in my mind. This is different from a term, as I am defining it.

The question is, what distinguishes a "word" from a "morpheme" and from a "sentence" in agglutinative languages? How do you break things down? What does it feel like to speak in an agglutinative language, are their clear separate concepts, or do things just morph from one state into the next in sort of a fluid motion, where there's not really words or even sentences, but just a flow of meaning? Or are there, in fact, words, in all these languages (in every language)? That is, is there a clear separation between "sentences" and "sentence parts"?

In working on a dictionary, I need to figure out a decent way of [modeling](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/43736/how-a-learner-of-a-polysynthetic-language-like-arapaho-would-use-an-electronic-o) agglutinative languages. The idea of morphemes is solid, and constructing "morpheme chains" for more complex "terms" makes sense. But at what point do you create "two terms" out of the "one", or two parts instead of one? In agglutinative language, is everything just one, a "morpheme stream", or is this proposed "continuous stream" divided into discrete chunks in a clear way? If so, how do the boundaries that create these discrete chunks work? If not, then it is a continuous stream of meaning (which would be really interesting to consider coming from English!), and I would need to think about how to artificially discretize this stream.

Thank you for the insight/help. Doesn't need to be a crystal clear definitive answer, just painting a rough vision of how discretization works would be extremely valuable.

#### Notes

https://arushalinguistics.org/publications/Kambarami_et_al_AWPAL_2021.pdf

> The first one is the prosodic or phonological level, which is based on
> how it sounds in spoken language (Hildebrandt, 2014). A second one is the
> orthographic or graphemic word, which is determined by how it is written
> down and is defined as a string of letters that are found between spaces or
> punctuation marks in writing or printing. The third definition is that of the
> morphological word, which considers how the words are formed and what
> part they play in speech. Yet another way of defining words is at the lexical
> or semantic level. This considers words to be the smallest units that carry
> meaning within a given language. Finally, words can also be defined at the
> syntactic level where each word is the smallest element of a sentence within
> a given language. Whilst there are overlaps and synergies between the
> above levels of word definition, there is no guarantee that each definition
> would yield exactly the same list of words in any language. In fact, they
> often do not.

[The informativeness of linguistic unit boundaries](https://www.italian-journal-linguistics.com/app/uploads/2021/05/3_Geertzen.pdf)

> This paper suggests that the inadequacy of current linguistic definitions is fully compatible with one traditional conception of words. On
> this view, words and other linguistic units are not independent components from which larger expressions are constructed but are, instead,
> abstracted from larger utterances.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_primes
https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:884408/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Some sentences require a definition, for example "a stitch in time saves nine". Phonemes also have definitions, it's just that the definitions are in terms of something "else" – I doubt that you seriously want there to be any linguistic objects that are undefined. So it's not clear what the point of this concept "terms" is.

There are two senses of "words". The popular one is "the thing surrounded by spaces" (there may be other conditions and punctuation marks in the definition). However, that first assumes that the language is written, which is often untrue. Not all written languages separate words with spaces, for example Sanskrit, Tibetan, Chinese, Japanese, Thai, Lao, Burmese and Khmer. Plus, ancient languages.

The alternative, sought by linguists, is to look for criteria that could be stated in terms of the innate language faculty, thus not in terms of writing conventions. This search, inputing more syntax-like structure to words, proved to be futile, especially in distinguishing words from morphemes or phrases. That is, hierarchical relations between morphemes can easily be encoded, but chunking those units into "morphemes within a word" and "words in a phrase" has been an irresolvable challenge. In Minimalism, the hunt for bright crosslinguistic lines distinguishing words from other things is over.

There are, however, language-specific criteria that justify the claim of wordhood, criteria that are used by linguists to trichotomize morphemes, words and phrases to some extent. The problem is that in order to use these criteria, you have to know the grammar of the language, and you have to get lucky and find that there are such criteria. The basic logic is "constituency", finding that the surface string {ab} acts as a unit for some purposes, and that *c* in {ab}c is excluded.

This alone is not enough to bootstrap the specific notion "word". One of the basic detectors of word-hood is not grammatical, it is based in speaker behavior – can you say it by itself, in the language? You should exclude academic influences, whereby any native speaker linguist can "say" any morpheme such as /-d/ "past tense" or /bon/ which is the root for "see" in many Bantu languages.

"Stress" has been awarded a privileged position as a diagnostic of word-hood. Typically, if we find that a particular sub-part of the sentence is the constituent for computing stress, we say that that constituent is the "word". Detection of "word" status relies heavily on phonological criteria, looking for words that apply "at the end of the ___" or "when two X's are in the same ___".

An almost non-phonological diagnostic of word-hood is allomorph-selection. Morphemes (in a more abstract semi-semantic sense, for example "past" or "plural") may be subject to contextual selection rules, such as the fact that some lexical items in English take a past tense entity that changes the quality of the vowel (sing, sang) when usually verbs take a suffix /d/. The property of allomorphy, selection between a set of underlying forms, is seen as a property of the morphological component (if it exists) which structures words, not phrases. However, English is **an** example of **a** language where we are not happy with such a strong statement. Nevertheless, if you accept "cumulative criteria", morphological allomorphy could be a useful diagnostic of word-hood in a specific language.

("Morphological allomorphy" distinguishes the two kinds of allomorphy that exist in the literature. One sense is any phonetic variation in the realization of a morpheme, so that a language might have a morpheme that is basically /maŋ/ but is realized as [mam, man, maɲ, maŋ] depending on the place of articulation of the next sound – a phonological rule creates the variation. Morphological allomorphy is the product of a non-phonological selection rule).

Using such criteria, the agglutinative structure of Bantu languages can be *mostly* be easily analyzed so  that we know when two morpheme are "in a word" vs. "in separate words", however there are almost always morphemes which seem to stand in the middle – not clearly within the word, not clearly separate. These are the clitics, where there does not seem to be any agreement as to how such sequences are to be written – except to the extent that there is a tendency towards writing clitics separately because they translate into some word in the local colonial language. Moreover, there is the famous case of the Sotho languages where spaces are inserted within words so that words look more like English (this mostly affects prefixes), despite the linguistic evidence for the unity of the word (that is, Sotho and Shona are not radically different in structure, it is only in writing conventions).

Dictionaries generally do not list the products of productive rules, so it might be more useful to think in terms of the distinction between "rule-governed" vs. "unpredictable".